# Adding a new field to my array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I got a nice **hotdealArray** of objects:

```
   [
        {
            "_id": "5908906b53075425aea0b16d",
            "property": "ATL-D406",
            "discount": 10,
            "hot": true
        },
        {
            "_id": "5908906b53075425aea0b16f",
            "property": "WAT-806",
            "discount": 20,
            "hot": true
        },
        {
            "_id": "5908906b53075425aea0b171",
            "property": "ANA-C202",
            "discount": 30,
            "hot": true
        }
    ]
```

I try this

```
hotdealArray[i].priceNight = result.res.priceNight;
```

Which give error: *Cannot set property 'priceNight' of undefined*

How can I add a new field to **hotdealArray**?

Here is my for loop as requested:

```
    for (var i=0; i<hotdealArray.length; i++) {
        var priceNight = 0;
        priceController.getPrice (
            { "body": { "propertyID": hotdealArray[i].property } }, 
            function(result) {
                if (result.error == true) {
                    throw new Error(result.err);
                } 
                priceNight = result.res.priceNight;
                console.log ("priceNight inside: " + priceNight);
            }
        );
        console.log ("priceNight outside: " + priceNight);
        hotdealArray[i].priceNight = priceNight;
    };
```

And in console log, it only shows this:

```
priceNight inside: 2160
priceNight inside: 2250
priceNight inside: 4455
priceNight inside: 1485
```

Comment: You need to provide more context. Either `hotdealArray` isn't the array you've posted at the time of reference, or `i` isn't 0, 1 or 2. We can't debug without more of your code.

Comment: @ArnavAggarwal If you do a `console.log(hotdealArray[i].property)` then you get a value. it already have values, I just need to add a new `priceNight`field to each record.

Comment: Please add the code you are using to loop through the array

Comment: Both ways you are trying are correct: https://jsfiddle.net/lixusrarnavo/f8g46hhk/ The problem is in either your `i` variable, or your array itself.

Comment: As with most questions of this nature, it is best if you can provide a [mcve] where we can see the code in action, demonstrating the issue. As @Lixus has demonstrated, a MCVE with the code you've provided does not demonstrate the issue.

Comment: Also what is Res?

Comment: @Lixus you are right - it works there.  Ok I gotta work on this some more and see why I cant add new fields.

Comment: ok I added the for loop.  I really do not understand this at all.  It can read the `hotdealArray[i].property` just fine

Comment: Oh It's a scoping error.  That changes everything.

Comment: can you acces the array inside the function?

Comment: @ThijsSteel no I cant - you are right.  And you are right also @James.  I cant access the array from inside `function(result) {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are other ways, but one way to avoid the scoping problem is to wrap the inner callback in an IIFE that explicitly defines `i` in that scope.

```
        function(result) {
            if (result.error == true) {
                throw new Error(result.err);
            } 
            console.log ("priceNight: " + result.res.priceNight);
            hotdealArray[i].priceNight = result.res.priceNight;
        }
```

becomes

```
(function (i) {
  return function(result) {
    if (result.error == true) {
      throw new Error(result.err);
    } 
    console.log ("priceNight: " + result.res.priceNight);
    hotdealArray[i].priceNight = result.res.priceNight;
  };
})(i);
```

Comment: this will probably work.  I just do not understand why I cannot access any of the scopes variables from inside the result function. Very strange.  Let me update the question so you can see.

Comment: how come I cannot access anything inside the `function(result) {}` - and how come I cant do anything after `priceController.getPrice ()` it completely ignores those lines

Comment: Since it's a callback function it won't have scope on any locally defined variables, callbacks tend to have global scope.  Either have globally scoped variables or set them as parameters in the IIFE, similar to what I did with `i`.

Comment: I think I figured it out - it actually do everything correctly, only problem is that the getPrice is not setup as a promise, so once the whole loop finishes, thats when the priceNight starts returning and at that time we are no longer inside the code/loop.   I need to isolate the call into a function and make that a promise.